# Show duplicates from mysql database that match a certain filter

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to show all duplicates in a database ([Example of the table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPEGM.png))
In this instance I would like:
First Name (meta_key > _field_5),
Last Name (meta_key > _field_6),
Email (meta_key > _field_7)

to be unique. So only show the duplicates that have these 3 parameters the same as the original one. In this case it's the 2 last results ([See the screenshot [Highlighted in red]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPEGM.png)).

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Jonah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pivoting can help here.

The below can find the earliest post_id if there are duplicate for the three values - i.e. the one you call original.

```
select min(post_id)
from (
    select post_id,
        max(case when meta_key = '_field_5' then meta_value end) as first_name,
        max(case when meta_key = '_field_6' then meta_value end) as last_name,
        max(case when meta_key = '_field_7' then meta_value end) as email
    from your_table
    where meta_key in ('_field_5', '_field_6', '_field_7')
    group by post_id
    ) t
group by first_name, last_name, email
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can exclude this one from the group to get the duplicates.

```
select post_id,
    max(case when meta_key = '_field_5' then meta_value end) as first_name,
    max(case when meta_key = '_field_6' then meta_value end) as last_name,
    max(case when meta_key = '_field_7' then meta_value end) as email
from your_table
where meta_key in ('_field_5', '_field_6', '_field_7')
group by post_id
having post_id != (
    select min(post_id)
    from (
        select post_id,
            max(case when meta_key = '_field_5' then meta_value end) as first_name,
            max(case when meta_key = '_field_6' then meta_value end) as last_name,
            max(case when meta_key = '_field_7' then meta_value end) as email
        from your_table
        where meta_key in ('_field_5', '_field_6', '_field_7')
        group by post_id
        ) t
    group by first_name, last_name, email
    having count(*) > 1
    );
```